# Pseudo Active Class and hover Class does not working

Tags: html, css

**hey anyone here have depth knowledge of css pseudo classes pls help. i apply active and hover class in anchor link button but doesn't work. i try in firefox,brave,chrome browser it doesn't work parfectly. in firefox active class work hover class doesn't and in brave or chrome hover class work active class doesn't.**
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYm0K.jpg) html code image
[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6j6A.jpg) css cose image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct and it's working.

```css
.btn:link, .btn:active {
text-transform: uppercase; background-color: white; display: inline-block; padding: 15px 40px; border-radius: 100px; transition: all 1s;}
.btn:hover {
transform: translateX(-3px); box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
.btn.active {
transform: translateY(-2px); box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
.btn-white {
text-decoration: none; color: #777;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato: 100,300,400, 700,900" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
    <script src="style.js" defer></script>
    <title>Natours | Exciting tours for adventurous people</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo-box">
            <img src="../starter/img/logo-white.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"> </div>
        <div class="text-box">
            <h1 class="heading-primary">
                <span class="main-text">outdoors </span>
                <span class="sub-text">is where life happen</span>
                <h1> <a href="#" class="btn btn-white" id="btn-tour">discover our tours</a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```